# Cypress find element from multiple elements based on text and click on it

Tags: list, find, element, each, cypress

Cypress: I want to find an element from the list of an element based on text and want to click on that

```
        cy.get('partie-room-list-item > div > div.content-block > span.partie-title').each(($elm , i) => {
            cy.get($elm).invoke('text').then((text) => {
            if (text === 'textinelement') {
                expect(text.trim()).equal('textinelement').click();
              cy.log(text)                  
            } 
          })




    });
```

[cypress find element and click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYauE.png)
https://www.screencast.com/t/p0rL6qexD5

Comment: Please see image in link

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Yes Maccurt
Thanks alot
how will I right Test for this scenario please
https://www.screencast.com/t/EIx6rbKnX4k8
Option need on off on single click

Comment: If the answer was provided by someone below, please upvote it or mark as answer . I will look at your other issue.. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Could you try below code and let me know the outcome. You could used `.text()` to get the text from the span element.

```
cy.get('partie-room-list-item > div > div > .partie-title').each(ele => {
           const eleText = "cypresssendfollowRequest";
            if (ele.text() === eleText) {
               ele.click();
           }
      });
```

Comment: as off 2023 ele.click has been deprecated, use .trigger('click')

Answer (score 2):

I am just guessing here. If you post your HTML I might be able to help you

```
cy.get('.partie-title').contains('textinelement').click()
```

looking at your image it would be like this

```
cy.get('.partie-title').contains('cypresssendfollowRequest').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
it("This test is for selecting a single element based on text",()=>{
    cy.visit('http://automationpractice.com/index.php')
    cy.get("[title='Women']").each(($element, index)=>{
        console.log("Object is "+ $element.text())
        if($element.text()=='Women'){
            cy.get($element).click()
        }
    })
})
```

or

```
it("This test is for selecting a single element based on text",()=>{
        cy.visit('http://automationpractice.com/index.php')
        cy.get("[title='Women']").contains('Women').click()                 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `cy.contains()` ([see documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains)).

For example:

```js
cy.contains('textinelement').click();
```

You can also add specificity so it only looks for text within a specified selector:

```js
cy.contains('.partie-title', 'textinelement').click();
```

Comment: This would work if the textinelement is unique, if it repeats on several elements it would return an array and you would still need to use .each()